# Failed to install psycopg2 on ubuntu docker with pip3

Tags: pip, psycopg2

Many people had this issue so I could read a lot and try to solve it but I could not. I created a docker container with Ubuntu and I am trying to `pip3 install psycopg2` package. I first thought that my environment was not properly defined but it does not work also for the root user with the following error. I have installed `libpq-dev` and `python3-dev` packages with `apt-get install` command and I can see them in in in `usr/share/doc/`. I have also tried to install psycopg2-binary as suggested in the error but it did not solve. Is the folder `usr/share/doc/` the good place for the packages? Any help to debug would be appreciated.

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gg_ryie1/psycopg2_af453b490b424518af45da724e40a56e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gg_ryie1/psycopg2_af453b490b424518af45da724e40a56e/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vodm8cxv
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gg_ryie1/psycopg2_af453b490b424518af45da724e40a56e/
  Complete output (38 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat
-Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100017 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:0:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

Comment: do you have `python-dev` installed on your system?

Comment: @T0ny1234 only `python3-dev` as I use python3.8

Comment: is `gcc` also installed? You can try installing `python3.8-dev` or whatever version of python you have and `build-essential` too.

Comment: @T0ny1234 yes gcc is installed. I managed to install psycopg2 at the root level (which is not what I want) with the command `sudo apt-get update -y` followed by `sudo apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2`. But it is still not possible when I change user and enter virtualenv. So there may be something wrong with the virtualenv

Comment: @T0ny1234 thank you so much installing python3.8-dev did it. I would like to learn why as I am not sure..